# Pass selectedItem to next Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm little bit new with razor pages / MVC. I have ProjectController which use ViewBag. In View I can display this EnumList. I want to Pass to next Controller the Model.ProjectId, and the SelectedItem.

**I tried Something like this:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    @{ 
        var parms = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"ProjectId", Model.Id.ToString() },
            {"Event", ((int)ViewBag.SelectedState).ToString()}
        };
    }
```

The problem with this: The SelectedState doesnt updated when I select new Item from the DropDownList. And the request will be always like this: https://localhost:port/Event/Create?ProjectId=1&Event=1

**My controller:**

```
private void CreateViewBagsDetail(string mode, string title)
    {
        ViewBag.Mode = mode;
        ViewBag.ModeTitle = title;
        var projectStateList = GetState<Datas.Enums.ProjectStateEnum>();
        ViewBag.ProjectStateList = projectStateList;
        ViewBag.SelectedState = projectStateList.SelectedValue;
    }

public SelectList GetState<T>()
    {
        List<string> events = new List<string>();
        var enumNames = (string[])Enum.GetNames(typeof(T));

        for (int i = 1; i < enumNames.Length; i++)
        {
            T enumElement = (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), enumNames[i]);
            events.Add((enumElement as Enum).GetDescription());
        }

        SelectList eventList = new SelectList(events);

        return eventList;
    }
```

**My View:**

```
@model Datas.Entities.Project
<h2>@ViewData["Title"]</h2>
<div class="row top-card">
    <div class="col-md-2 card">
        <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Események</label>
            <select asp-for="State" class="form-control" asp-items="@(SelectList)ViewBag.ProjectStateList"></select>
        </div>
             <a class="btn bg-teal btn-block waves-effect" asp-controller="Event" asp-action="Create" asp-all-route-data="parms">Felvitel</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use TempData or Session in and use where you want it.

Comment: My HTML request: if I click the button is: https://localhost:port/Event/Create?ProjectId=1&Event=1. Event always 1 because it's doesn't update when I select another element from list.

Comment: i did not understand properly. if you need drop down value on change than you should call drop down change event through client side

Comment: Havent delved into RazorPages yet, but cant you just go javascript/ajax if you want the same functionality?

Comment: @mahlatse Yes with js or jquery or something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Bear in mind, you might need to change a few things, but the general idea is this

If you have a button at the end that does the whole **GET** request, you can put it like this

```js
$("#some_button").click(function() {
      var url = '@Url.Action("Create","Event")?projectid=' + @ {
        Model.Id.ToString()
      } + '&/event=' + $("#select_id option:selected").value;
      window.location = url;
    }
```

Now if you are looking for a **POST** request, things become a bit different, the way you specified your question, is the same as a GET post where you send the parameters as a query string on the URL, for a post, you would need to create a form element, and it should be generally easier to do a post in aspnet  as you would need to consider the default modelbinder.

as long as the your receiving method has the correct values set up, you should be able to recieve the values on the other side.